# How to find out a specific value from history data based on date mapping in SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Table A and Table B. And the desired results. See the picture below

Table A :

```html
| ID            | Point_date    | TENANT    |
|-----------    |------------   |--------   |
| 114396845     | 1/5/21        | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 1/5/21        | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 3/30/21       | vp.com    |
| 114396845     | 4/5/21        | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 5/27/21       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 7/22/21       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 7/22/21       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 11/29/21      | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 11/29/21      | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 12/27/21      | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 1/24/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 1/28/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 1/29/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/6/22        | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/8/22        | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/10/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/10/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/10/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/14/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/18/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/18/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/23/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 2/23/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 3/6/22        | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 3/10/22       | vp.com    |
| 756392741     | 3/10/22       | vp.com    |
```

Table B :

```html
| ID            | TENANT    | STAGE             | Change_date   |
|-----------    |--------   |------------------ |-------------  |
| 114396845     | vp.com    | stage1_Newbi      | 12/14/20      |
| 114396845     | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     | 1/6/21        |
| 756392741     | vp.com    | stage1            | 4/30/21       |
| 756392741     | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   | 7/23/21       |
| 756392741     | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  | 2/15/22       |
| 756392741     | vp.com    | stage12_PreMate   | 4/9/22        |
| 756392741     | vp.com    | stage13_Respe     | 7/18/22       |
```

Desired Results :

```html
| ID            | Point_date    | TENANT    | Stage             |
|-----------    |------------   |--------   |------------------ |
| 114396845     | 1/5/21        | vp.com    | stage1_Newbi      |
| 114396845     | 1/5/21        | vp.com    | stage1_Newbi      |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     |
| 114396845     | 1/8/21        | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     |
| 114396845     | 3/30/21       | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     |
| 114396845     | 4/5/21        | vp.com    | stage3_B_Tool     |
| 756392741     | 5/27/21       | vp.com    | stage1            |
| 756392741     | 7/22/21       | vp.com    | stage1            |
| 756392741     | 7/22/21       | vp.com    | stage1            |
| 756392741     | 11/29/21      | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 11/29/21      | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 12/27/21      | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 1/24/22       | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 1/28/22       | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 1/29/22       | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 2/6/22        | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 2/8/22        | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 2/10/22       | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 2/10/22       | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 2/10/22       | vp.com    | stage5_per_Tool   |
| 756392741     | 2/14/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 2/18/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 2/18/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 2/23/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 2/23/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 3/6/22        | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 3/10/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
| 756392741     | 3/10/22       | vp.com    | stage6_Unbonused  |
```

I want all the data from Table A and want to add another column 'stage' from table B. However, if the point_date is lower than change_date then I would like to take values from historical data as per that date. You can see the desired result in this snapshot.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It's recommended to provide data / code / and additional stuff like error messages / exceptions etc. as (formatted) **Text** rather than attached imaged when asking questions because the info can get found via web search etc. that way and get copied&pasted by the readers who want to help rather than retyping all that stuff and having to buy new optical glasses for decipherment

Comment: @StefanWuebbe - Thanks Stefan, it makes sense. I am new to Stack Overflow and finding difficulty in pasting data in text format. Would you mind helping me here?

Comment: Sure date/time formats / notation would depend a little on the DBMS make and model that you use. The following sequence would for example work in PostgreSQL 14 and others: `Create Table test (id Int, myDate Date); Insert Into test (id, myDate) Values (1, '2022-7-20'); Select * From test;`

Comment: See also https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html

Comment: You can also experiment on a few "playgrounds", e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: And also https://dbfiddle.uk/ (which currently seems to be unusually offline)

Comment: @StefanWuebbe - Thank you, for now, I updated my questions. You can see the proper format. Could you please help me with how can I achieve these values?

Comment: Your Question looks quite well prepared now, +1; I believe Snowflake is based on MySql, right? This fiddle does not seem to accept your proposed 'mm/dd/YY' string notation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=649a258b8c520bff098e46e02a5a41ef

Comment: @StefanWuebbe -  I didn't understand. I am looking for SQL query to solve this question.

Comment: You have tags for both `mysql` and `snowflake-cloud-data-platform`. They use different SQL dialects. Can you remove the tag that does not apply?

Comment: @GregPavlik - Done. Would you able to help me to achieve the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple query finds the closest CHANGE_DATE backward in time from POINT_DATE:

```
select max(CHANGE_DATE) from TABLE_B B 
where CHANGE_DATE <= POINT_DATE and A.ID = B.ID
```

Now we can project that as a column when selecting from TABLE_A:

```
select   ID
        ,POINT_DATE
        ,TENANT
        ,(select max(CHANGE_DATE) from TABLE_B B 
          where CHANGE_DATE <= POINT_DATE and A.ID = B.ID) CHANGE_DATE
from     TABLE_A A
```

This gives us an (abbreviated) intermediate table that looks like this:

| ID | POINT_DATE | TENANT | CHANGE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | vp.com | 2020-12-14 00:00:00 |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | vp.com | 2020-12-14 00:00:00 |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | vp.com | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 |

As you can see, we can now join TABLE_A and TABLE_B on the combination of ID and CHANGE_DATE. We can join them in a subquery or CTE depending on your preference:

```
with A as
(
select   ID
        ,POINT_DATE
        ,TENANT
        ,(select max(CHANGE_DATE) from TABLE_B B 
          where CHANGE_DATE <= POINT_DATE and A.ID = B.ID) CHANGE_DATE
from     TABLE_A A
)
select A.ID, A.POINT_DATE, A.TENANT, B.STAGE
from A left join TABLE_B B on A.ID = B.ID and A.CHANGE_DATE = B.CHANGE_DATE
;
```

This give us the following abbreviated output:

| ID | POINT_DATE | TENANT | STAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | vp.com | stage1_Newbi |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | vp.com | stage1_Newbi |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | vp.com | stage3_B_Tool |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | vp.com | stage3_B_Tool |
| 114396845 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | vp.com | stage3_B_Tool |

Comment: I just realized something... The subselect should use `CHANGE_DATE <= POINT_DATE` instead of `CHANGE_DATE < POINT_DATE`. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Greg Pavlik. I modified that part in my original project. :)

Comment: I figured you'd catch that. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this should work if it's SQL Server.

```
SELECT ID, Point_date, TENANT,
(SELECT TOP 1 STAGE FROM Table_B WHERE ChangeDate < tblA.Point_date) as Stage
FROM Table_A as tblA
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Thompson. But I have multiple IDs and history for that IDs with multiple tenant information. So it didn't work. Also, I use snowflake to run the qeury. Is there any better way?